# Sum up invoice amounts based upon IDs that exist in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table which contains invoice lines by row and 6 columns where an employee ID can be tagged to that invoice. Employee IDs cannot be duplicated in a row, however the same employee ID can exist in different columns for different invoice lines. In the table below, REP 1 should have a total amount of 500.

[image]

I want to be able to sum up the total amounts by employee ID(REP 1, REP 2, etc..). I can do this with a large union query, but the issue is that I have a list of about 450 employee IDs that I need to sum up. Is there a way I can have one query spit out a list of employee IDs and their total amounts?

Comment: Based on the evidence (2 tags versus 1), I removed the mysql tag.  If your question is not about SQL Server, please tag appropriately.

Comment: First let's clarify which product do you use: MySQL or ms sql server. Also, is it an option to denormalise your data structure and have the slots in records, rather than in columns.

Comment: My apologies, I updated the tag. Version is Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `cross apply`:

```
select v.e, sum(t.amount)
from t cross apply
     (values (slot1), (slot2), (slot3), (slot4), (slot5), (slot6)) v(e)
group by v.e;
```

Note:  This assumes that you are using SQL Server.

Comment: Does this account for all the potential distinct values in each of the slots?

Answer (score 1):

Joining the tables is one way...

```
select e.employee_id,
       sum(i.amount)
  from invoice i,
  join employee e on (e.employee_id in (i.slot1, i.slot2, i.slot3, i.slot4, i.slot5, i.slot6))
 group by e.employee_id;
```

An alternative way...

```
select employee_id,
       sum(amount)
from (
    select slot1 employee_id, sum(amount) amount from invoice group by slot1 union
    select slot2, sum(amount) from invoice group by slot2 union all
    select slot3, sum(amount) from invoice group by slot3 union all
    select slot4, sum(amount) from invoice group by slot4 union all
    select slot5, sum(amount) from invoice group by slot5 union all
    select slot6, sum(amount) from invoice group by slot6
) as q1
group by employee_id;
```

Comment: @ RMathis, does your alternative query account for all of the IDs in all 6 columns even though you're grouping by the employee_id from the first slot?

Comment: yes...  in the first quyery, the join to the employee table allows each employee to be given credit.  The second query unions each the aggregation results for each slot in the derived table which is then aggregated together one last time.  The first query determines the column names so all slots provide identifiers in the employee_id column and all sum(amounts) are given the name amount.   Union all is the better choice - I updated the answer accordingly.